# Not working onClick scroll left or right products in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of products displayed horizontally.

[image]

I need to make a working on click Left or Right btns, to scroll next product into view.

This is my scrollProducts function which not working:

```
  const scrollProducts = isRight => {
    const $document = document.querySelector(".prodcuts")
    if (!$document) {
      return
    }
    productsRef.current.scrollLeft = isRight
      ? productsRef.current.scrollLeft + $document.clientWidth
      : productsRef.current.scrollLeft - $document.clientWidth
  }
```

JSX part:

```
      <section className="prodcuts" ref={productsRef}>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => scrollProducts(false)}>Left</button>
          <button onClick={() => scrollProducts(true)}>Right</button>
        </div>
        <Row styles={styles.productCards}>
          {site.siteMetadata.data.map(product => (
            <ProductCard key={product.name} {...product} />
          ))}
        </Row>
      </section>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Hi Marks looks like you need horizontally scroll ?

Comment: Unrelated, but you have a typo in your class "prodcuts". Also, since you already have a reference to it, why do you need to use a query selector to access that element?

Comment: @MehulJariwala Yes, right

Comment: @DBS yes you are right, I really don't need that querySelector

Comment: you can feel free to reach me i will connect and see issue ping hi mjariwala98#4797 on discord

Comment: @MehulJariwala that will be awsome, thank you anyway. 
I will ping you later on discord and when you have time let's see :)